# Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Navbar.Collapse> (16:12)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I get Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Navbar.Collapse> (16:12) error, It says there is no closing tag for <Navbar.Collapse> but there is,
here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

function Header() {
    return (
            <header>
                <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Container>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Full error

```
Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Navbar.Collapse> (16:12)

  14 |                     <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
  15 |                 </Nav>
> 16 |             </Container>
     |             ^
  17 |                 </Navbar.Collapse>
  18 |                 </Navbar>
  19 |             </header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the  `</Navbar.Collapse>` needs to be before the `</container>` tag